# How to replacing all missing values in numpy array with 0 and displaying the last 15 values of the attribute

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I have an Array X with is (398,5)

I am trying to replace all missing values in this array with 0's and printing out the last 15 values of the attribute with missing values.

I did convert X into a numpy array using a dataframe.  I am told that I will be able to tell the attribute with missing values by looking at the DataFrame info I generated earlier.

My dataframe is X_df

I'm a bit confused by this so any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

For more clarrification.  I had a dataframe with nan values called X_df

I turned that into a numpy array called X

I then replaced all nan values of X with 0 using the code below.  He wants me to print out the last 15 changed rows.  That is where I am a bit stuck

```
index = np.isnan(X)
X[index] = 0
```

Comment: not sure what you are asking...you've managed to replace all values with 0 .. now what do you mean by display last 15 values of the attribute?

Comment: How can you convert an array into an array using a DataFrame? Can you provide some more context for this?

Comment: Displaying last 15 values of the attribute with missing values.  My attritubes in the dataframe are cylinders, displacement, horsepower, weight and acceleration.

Comment: X_df was a dataframe.  I converted that dataframe into a numpy array called X

Comment: Technically the last 15 changed rows would all be zero because that's all you've changed. Think you mean the last 15 rows, as that's what the accepted answer does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a DataFrame:

```
df.where(~np.isnan(df), 0) # replace NaNs with 0
df.tail(15) # show last 15 rows
```

On a numpy ndarray:

```
a[np.where(np.isnan(a))] = 0 # Set NaNs to 0
a[-15:, :] # Last 15 rows
```

Comment: That won't work as I'm trying to replace values in a numpy array and not a dataframe